# perl syntax check without loading c library

Tags: c, perl, dynamic, libraries, syntax-checking

I would like to check syntax of my perl module (as well as for imports), but I don't want to check for dynamic loaded c libraries.

If I do:

```
perl -c path_to_module
```

I get:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module B::Hooks::OP::Check in @INC
```

because B::Hooks::OP::Check are loading some dynamic c libraries and I don't want to check that...

Comment: If a library isn't available, how do you know if it's a C or pure Perl library? Do you have a well-defined list of libraries you want to ignore, or should all missing libraries be trapped? (In the latter case, how do you plan to distinguish a load failure from a real error?)

Comment: This error:

Can't locate loadable object for module B::Hooks::OP::Check

is different than:

Can't locate B/Hooks/OP/Checkaa.pm (I've changed name of import here)

I just don't want to load dynamic c libraries to so I can check perl syntax anywhere where modules are...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Modules can affect the scripts that use them in many ways, including how they are parsed.

For example, if a module exports

```
sub f() { }
```

Then

```
my $f = f+4;
```

means

```
my $f = f() + 4;
```

But if a it were to export

```
sub f { }
```

the same code means

```
my $f = f(+4);
```

As such, modules must be loaded to parse the script that loads it. To load a module is simply to execute it, be it written in Perl or C.

---

That said, some folks put together [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI) to address the needs of people like you. It's not perfect —it can't be perfect for the reasons previously stated— but it will give useful results nonetheless.

---

By the way, the proper way to syntax check a module is

```
perl -e'use Module;'
```

Using `-c` can give errors where non exists and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax checker loads the included libraries because they might be applying changes to the syntax. If you're certain that this is not happening, you could prevent the inclusion by manipulating the loading path and providing a fake `b::Hooks::OP::Check`.